# Can I install an x86 version of XP on an acer aspire one

Tags: windows-xp, acer-aspire-one

I have bought an acer aspire one which has the intel atom processor running linux and am having difficulty getting a 3G USB modem (huwaei e220) working with it. I have spent a significant amount of time trying to get this working but as the modem is not supported on Linux I have now decided to give in and install xp.

Is there a specific version of xp that I need for this processor? or can I install the standard x86 version

Answer (score 2):

Atom **implements** the x86 (IA-32) instruction set. As far as I understand, you should have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can install the standard x86 version.

In fact, take a look at this post.  Looks like the guy had the exact same problem as you.

http://www.osnews.com/story/20251/Aspire_One_Installing_and_Running_Windows_XP

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Standard x86 version will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who makes your 3G router but I saw company X with a ton of reboxed recertified 3G routers for $49, but I don't know the requirements.

First, simply look up your model number and its requirements.

I have an Acer One and have used 20 different versions of Linux YLMF (Just like a copy of XP, and works so great), KXSTUDIO Puppy Linux, SLAMPPP (Be careful with SLAMPP; it's loaded with all types of web servers and all or 90% of them are open by default, but a great system for those that want to have a great server but don't want to install all the different programs. I like the way Slampp uses the CUPS printing system. They have version 4.x and it has nearly ever printer driver ever made pre-installed) plus Puppy Linux, Partition Magic (Great for working on a Windows machine that died), Damn Small Linux, Slax Linux and Mandrake's new version (I can't remember the name).

I have six more on my keychain, but they are at the other end of the house and I'm tired but the point is, the little old Acer Aspire One will handle a lot; I even have Windows 7 on one. It's slow as heck but lets me get some things done that the other OSs will not, so I put up with it.